# Getting an SQL errro trying to seed a new DB for project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Trying to create a database in an asp project and seed. Seem to be having issue issue with the ASPNetRoles and one of the parameters and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

> SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:
> Information: Executed DbCommand (108ms)
> [Parameters=[@__normalizedName_0='?' (Size = 256)],
> CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id],
> [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Name], [a].[NormalizedName] FROM
> [AspNetRoles] AS [a] WHERE [a].[NormalizedName] = @__normalizedName_0
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed
> DbCommand (104ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedName_0='?' (Size = 256)],
> CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id],
> [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Name], [a].[NormalizedName] FROM
> [AspNetRoles] AS [a] WHERE [a].[NormalizedName] = @__normalizedName_0
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed
> executing DbCommand (164ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 450), @p1='?'
> (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 256), @p3='?' (Size = 256)],
> CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO
> [AspNetRoles] ([Id], [ConcurrencyStamp], [Name], [NormalizedName])
> VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update:
> Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for
> context type 'CTI_Manager_App.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
> while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated in table 'login.dbo.AspNetRoles',
> column 'Id'. Truncated value: '7'. The statement has been terminated.

Here is my code.

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
 name: "AspNetRoles",
 columns: table => new
 {
     Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
     Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
     NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
     ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
 },
 constraints: table =>
 {
     table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
 });
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar");

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
                    .HasMaxLength(256);

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar")
                    .HasMaxLength(256);

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasName("RoleNameIndex");
                    

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
            });
```

Seed Code

```
    using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CTI_Manager_App.Data.Seeders
{
    public static class IdentityDataSeeder<TIdentityUser, TIdentityRole>
        where TIdentityUser : IdentityUser, new()
        where TIdentityRole : IdentityRole, new()
    {
        private const string DefaultAdminRoleName = "Administrators";
        private const string DefaultAdminUserEmail = "admin@example.com";
        private const string DefaultAdminUserPassword = "Secret1+";

        private static async Task CreateDefaultAdminRole(RoleManager<TIdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            // Make sure we have an Administrator role
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(DefaultAdminRoleName))
            {
                var role = new TIdentityRole
                {
                    Name = DefaultAdminRoleName
                };

                var roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if (!roleResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException($"Could not create '{DefaultAdminRoleName}' role");
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<TIdentityUser> CreateDefaultAdminUser(UserManager<TIdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@argon.com");
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new TIdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = DefaultAdminUserEmail,
                    Email = DefaultAdminUserEmail,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                };
                var userResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, DefaultAdminUserPassword);

                if (!userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException($"Could not create '{DefaultAdminUserEmail}' user");
                }
            }

            return user;
        }

        private static async Task AddDefaultAdminRoleToDefaultAdminUser(
            UserManager<TIdentityUser> userManager,
            TIdentityUser user)
        {
            // Add user to Administrator role if it's not already associated
            if (!(await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).Contains(DefaultAdminRoleName))
            {
                var addToRoleResult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, DefaultAdminRoleName);
                if (!addToRoleResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        $"Could not add user '{DefaultAdminUserEmail}' to '{DefaultAdminRoleName}' role");
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task SeedDataAsync(IServiceProvider services, ILogger logger) 
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TIdentityUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<TIdentityRole>>();

            var retries = 3;
            ensureCreated:
            try
            {
                await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (retries == 0)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                logger.LogWarning(ex, $"An error occurred while seeding the database ; maybe the server isn't currently running, will retry {retries} more times after 5 seconds");
                await Task.Delay(5000);

                retries -= 1;
                goto ensureCreated;
            }

            await CreateDefaultAdminRole(roleManager);
            var defaultAdminUser = await CreateDefaultAdminUser(userManager);
            await AddDefaultAdminRoleToDefaultAdminUser(userManager, defaultAdminUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am *not* voting to close; just downvoting. The error is quite self-explanatory: `String or binary data would be truncated in table 'login.dbo.AspNetRoles', column 'Id'. Truncated value: '7'`. So you need to check what is the value in the table before the migration start. *7* is strange value for ID - usually, it is Guid. You need to do much more troubleshooting before throwing the towel!

Comment: Yeah I have for about 6 hours now. I have scoured google and make a change and get a different error each time each one about the NormalizeName. I am actually new and learning....

Comment: @Felix and I did check the value its blank. It created the tables and columns but nothing else.

Comment: you don't show your seeding code. So, how can we help you. And `migrationBuilder.CreateTable()` isn't really *your* code - it is generated from migration!

Comment: If Id is in fact a string, why haven’t you set MaxLength on Id like you have for Name and NormalizedName? If you declare something as an nvarchar it defaults to nvarchar(1), if you can only have 1 character then either Id is a terrible name or you don’t expect more than a handful of rows. Similarly ConcurrencyStamp is an nvarchar(1) which doesn’t make much sense to me at all.

Comment: @Felix I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the column type of the Id column in your model builder.

```
b.Property<string>("Id").HasColumnType("nvarchar");
```

The default max length of `nvarchar` is 1 in SQL Server. Your id value is being truncated to a single character because that's all your schema has room for.

If you specify a max length constraint for that column that is large enough to hold your Id value, the error will be resolved.

Comment: Same error for the most part if i set to nvarchar(256)

Comment: Even if the default width for nvarchar is 1, `nvarchar(1)` is sufficient to store the value that's throwing the error (i.e. "7"), no?

Comment: @AarinMichaelBailey - What type are you using for TIdentityRole when you instantiate the IdentityDataSeeder?

Comment: A string. I think I need to dig a little more as a module or misconfiguration in another model. I’m going to start over and see what I can come up with. It’s possible I’m trying to edit something auto generated and don’t fully understand how to seed a file